# SQL Server : two tables from different database has different default sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different database, I need move away from one DB so I replicate same scenario where table should be loaded from `INSERT INTO SELECT *` statement.

However, when I do the same thing for new DB the table has different ordering from the original one.

e.g

DB1 - tbl_temp
DB2 - tbl_temp

```
INSERT INTO DB1.tbl_temp
col1,
col2,
    SELECT col1, col2 
    FROM DB3.tbl_source
```

Result is: when I use `SELECT * FROM DB1.tbl_temp`

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| def | 456 |

```
INSERT INTO DB2.tbl_temp
col1,
col2,
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM DB3.tbl_source
```

Result is: when I use `SELECT * FROM DB2.tbl_temp`

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| def | 456 |
| abc | 123 |

Both has same source but result has different order, is there any configuration needed to fix the issue ? Thank you

Comment: If you want a specific order, do `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The order of the rows is never guaranteed. Tables rows don't follow any order per se.

Comment: I mean in my example there must be something between DB right ?

Comment: both table uses same sql statement and same source, but how does the result order is different ?

Comment: Because the order you get is not guaranteed and will depend on the execution plan and in some cases what physical page the rows happen to be stored on

Comment: @MartinSmith So you mean this is randomly generated ? I tried doing same steps again in DB1 and DB2 with new table but the order still persists

Comment: No - I never said it was random. It is not guaranteed and will depend on the execution plan. SQL Server isn't going to go out of its way to randomise it. If the returned order is important to you you need an `ORDER BY`. It is that simple

Comment: Okay thanks will leave this mystery here. btw my last resort is to use ORDER BY

Comment: well that is the **only** way to get a guaranteed result so it should be your first resort